# How to run Tasks in a non-GUI thread using Threadpools

Tags: java, multithreading, task

I'm calculating three different values at the same time which is depending on the level state of my application, so I'm using Tasks for a faster calculation. However if I want to change the level during calculation it's not possible, because all the buttons are disabled during the calculation.

I've found out that I cannot cancel the tasks because my GUI freezes until the tasks are finished. Therefore I cannot cancel tasks, because they are already finished

My GUI has this buttonclick event

```
buttonIncreaseLevel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        increaseLevelButtonActionPerformed(event);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

It increases a level and starts this method

```
        createTask(taskLeftEdge,EdgeType.LEFT);
        createTask(taskBottomEdge,EdgeType.BOTTOM);
        createTask(taskRightEdge,EdgeType.RIGHT);

        pool.submit(taskRightEdge);
        pool.submit(taskBottomEdge);
        pool.submit(taskLeftEdge);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("[Future] Started to wait for task (future)");
                    // A task is also its own future
                    ArrayList taskR = (ArrayList) taskRightEdge.get();
                    ArrayList taskB = (ArrayList) taskBottomEdge.get();
                    ArrayList taskL = (ArrayList) taskLeftEdge.get();

                    System.out.println("[Future] " + taskR);
                    System.out.println("[Future] " + taskB);
                    System.out.println("[Future] " + taskL);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FUN3KochFractalFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        ).start();
```

The method for creating a task

```
    private void createTask(Task task, EdgeType type){
        if (task != null) {
            application.cancelProgress(type);
            task.cancel();
        }
        // There's a new task that performs some work
        switch(type){
            case LEFT:
                taskLeftEdge = new EdgeGeneratorTask("Task: " + taskNumber, type, this, application);
                task = taskLeftEdge;
                edges.addAll(koch.generateLeftEdge());
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                taskBottomEdge = new EdgeGeneratorTask("Task: " + taskNumber, type, this, application);
                task = taskBottomEdge;
                edges.addAll(koch.generateBottomEdge());
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                taskRightEdge = new EdgeGeneratorTask("Task: " + taskNumber, type, this, application);
                task = taskRightEdge;
                edges.addAll(koch.generateRightEdge());
                break;
        }
        taskNumber++;

        application.setProgress( task, type);
    }
```

And the Task itself. The class Kochfractal is where the calculations are made

```
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(EdgeGeneratorTask.class.getName());
    private final String id;
    private EdgeType type;
    private KochFractal calc;
    private FUN3KochFractalFX application;


    public EdgeGeneratorTask(String id, EdgeType type, KochManager manager, FUN3KochFractalFX main) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        calc = new KochFractal(manager);
        application = main;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Edge> call() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
        switch(type){
            case LEFT:
                edges = calc.generateLeftEdge();
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                edges = calc.generateBottomEdge();
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                edges = calc.generateRightEdge();
                break;
        }

        int MAX = edges.size();
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
            updateProgress(i, MAX);
            updateMessage(id + " " + i);
        }
        return edges;
    }
```

I expect these threads to be cancelled, with an action on my JavaFX GUI.
The threads should run on a background Thread instead of the GUI thread itself

Comment: Please show us the code of the createTask method.

Comment: Side note: since GUI events such Action events are already executed on the JavaFX Application Thread, Platform.runLater can usually be omitted. The handler registration code could be reduced to: `buttonIncreaseLevel.setOnAction(this::increaseLevelButtonActionPerformed)`

Comment: I added the createtask method and the Task itself

Comment: The for loop in EdgeGeneratorTask.call doesn't really do much execpt iterating over an integer and update the GUI. Maybe you want to put the logic inside the loop? It doesn't explain however why the GUI is freezing...

Comment: It's more like the main thread is waiting on the tasks to finish, while i'm using the Executorservice to submit tasks. So is this the wrong method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "GUI freezes"? Does it really freeze completely (menus, button etc.) or is e.g. the cancel button still clickable but has no effect?